# SQL Server XML Typed Column Size variance

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-schema-collection

In Sql server if we create a xml column with a schema associated to it (typed XML) will this help in reducing the space required to store the actual data.

Example if i create 2 tables with XML column considering the data is same in both the tables one table is created with typed xml and other with untyped xml will there be any difference in space occupied by the tables  ???.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the particular datatypes and schema involved, apparently.  [This conversation](http://www.mombu.com/microsoft/sql-server-xml/t-storage-size-of-typed-vs-untyped-xml-columns-336033.html) has more details for you.